# How to get XmlInputParser work with self-closing XML tags?

Tags: hadoop, xml-parsing

I am trying to load XML files from [SE data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/)* into HDFS using MapReduce. These XML files consist of a number of `<row>` elements (enclosed in a top-level "category"), like so:

```
<badges>
  <row Id="1" UserId="1" Name="Organizer" Date="2009-07-15T06:51:46.370" />
  <row Id="2" UserId="3" Name="Organizer" Date="2009-07-15T06:51:46.387" />
  <row Id="4" UserId="1" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2009-07-15T06:51:46.447" />
  ...
</badges>
```

I want each "row" to be processed by a separate `map()` function, and have configured `org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.XmlInputFormat`'s start and end tags as below:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.set(XmlInputFormat.START_TAG_KEY, "<row>");
config.set(XmlInputFormat.END_TAG_KEY, "</row>");
```

However, this fails to parse the XML file, because the `<row>` element is self-closing. How do I get this to work, without artificially "closing" the self-closing tags?

- Linking to SE blog rather than directly to the data dump, to prevent dead link in case location changes in future.

Comment: Note: I didn't find any suitable question similar to this one here, if this is already answered, please feel free to close or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat ugly hack. Change the `START_TAG_KEY` and `END_TAG_KEY` as below:

```
config.set(XmlInputFormat.START_TAG_KEY, "<row");
config.set(XmlInputFormat.END_TAG_KEY, "/>");
```

The "keys" are being used like delimiters, and accept any string, rather than just XML tags. Not a "clean" solution, and may stop working on future implementations, but it gets the work done *now*.

Note: I figured it out while I was midway through posting the question. This seems rather obvious in hindsight, but I decided to go ahead with the post anyway, so that someone may find it useful in future.